# BB FlashBack Player convert exe to mp4

Tags: video, exe, mp4

I have a `.exe` file created in **[BB FlashBack Player](http://www.flashbackrecorder.com/express)** version 3. I want to convert it to mp4 format. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

**1)** Your Question is **off-topic**. This is a programming forum.

**2)** 
Did you follow the steps from manual? **[How to Export MP4 file](http://community.flashbackrecorder.com/support/solutions/articles/12000012855-how-to-export-html5-compatible-mp4-files)**.

> To export MP4 files... on the MPEG4 export options window you should:
>
> - Select the "Microsoft Media Foundation" option on the Codec tab. MP4    files generated using the openh264 option can have playback
>     problems    in Chrome.
> - Turn on the "Allow streaming" option on the Video and Sound Quality    tab.

**3)** `.exe` is a Windows application, it is not a video format. Apart from hacking that Windows app to extract the audio/video data, I think your option is to do another screen-capture whre you record the running `.exe` file.

If you want a video format use either `.avi`, `.flv` or `.mp4`